# 2 digit sums and all combinations for each sum

Tags: c

Using the digits 1 though 9, without repeating the same digit, I made this table of sums comprised of adding two digits together and all possible combinations for each sum.  I am trying to write a program in C to find all sums by adding 2 digits together and each of their combinations and then print out this chart.  I am trying to use for loops to write this program and have become stuck.  I can get the first initial sums to print out, but it is getting the combinations that has me stumped now.  I do not know if I am on the right track or not.  Any suggestions and help would be greatly appreciated.  My chart, code written so far, and the print out for the current code is below.

This is what I want my program to do:

This chart lists all the sums comprised of 2 digits and all the possible combinations to make each sum.

```
    2 Digit Sums
Sum Combinations
3   1+2
4   1+3
5   1+4, 2+3
6   1+5, 2+4
7   1+6, 2+5, 3+4
8   1+7, 2+6, 3+5
9   1+8, 2+7, 3+6, 4+5
10  1+9, 2+8, 3+7, 4+6
11  2+9, 3+8, 4+7, 5+6
12  3+9, 4+8, 5+7
13  4+9, 5+8, 6+7
14  5+9, 6+8
15  6+9, 7+8
16  7+9
17  8+9
```

This is the code I have been able to write successfully:

```
/* Thus program uses the digits 1 - 9 to find all possible sums composed of two
digits, non repeating, and all possible combinations of digits to obain the sums. */
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int S, A, B;
    A = 1;
    B = A + 1;
    S = A + B;
    printf("\t\t2 Digit Sums\n\n");
    printf("Sum\tCombinations\n");
    for(B; B <= 8; ++B)
    {
        S = A + B;
        printf("%d\t%d + %d\n", S, A, B);
    }
    for(A; (A < B && A !=B); ++A)
    {
        S = A + B;
        printf("%d\t%d + %d\n", S, A, B);
    }       
    return(0);
}
```

This is the output of my code:

```
                2 Digit Sums
Sum     Combinations
3       1 + 2
4       1 + 3
5       1 + 4
6       1 + 5
7       1 + 6
8       1 + 7
9       1 + 8
10      1 + 9
11      2 + 9
12      3 + 9
13      4 + 9
14      5 + 9
15      6 + 9
16      7 + 9
17      8 + 9
Press any key to continue...
```

Comment: Try recursion instead of loops.

Comment: If you plan on expanding the program, then you will have to do it using recursion

Answer (score 1):

If the scope of the problem is limited like this one, you can solve it through Brute Force -- just try them all out.  There are only 17 * 9 * 9 variations to check which isn't a lot really.

With three loops (pseudo code):

```
for each value of possible_sum (2-17)

    print possible_sum

    for each value of addend1 (1-9)

       for each value of addend2 (1-9) 

       if ( addend1 + addend2 = possible_sum ) 
       then

           print addend1 and addend2

       end if

       end for addend2

    end for addend1

end for possible_sum
```

A problem left for you is to figure out how to eliminate the symmetrical solutions (4+5 and 5+4), it's easy if you look at the patterns in your solution (note how the first addend relates to the second one).  There are lots of ways to speed up even this brute-force method if you think about it carefully.

With larger data sets ("all three digit addends...") a better algorithm would be needed.